# Limiting requested field set of Kendo UI Grid bound to OData service

Tags: odata, kendo-ui

How to configure the Kendo UI grid, so it would issue requests only for specific (displayed) fields?

In my instance, a Kendo UI grid is bound to a OData service. The service exposes a table with many (200+) fields. The app allows users to configure displayed field set of the Grid, set initial filters and sort parameters. The app configures the Grid, which then goes off and queries OData service.

The grid kendo.Data.DataSource is defined as:

```
var gridDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    type: "odata",
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "@Url.Content(dynDataSource.Url)",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json"
        }
    },
    pageSize: @Model.MaxPageSize,
    serverPaging: true,
    serverFiltering: true,
    serverSorting: true,
    filter: ...
}
```

Here's a sample request issued by the Grid (captured by Firebug):

```
http://localhost:22411/Data/Comp?%24inlinecount=allpages&%24top=1000&%24filter=DistrictCode+eq+%27460800%27
```

This returns all the fields of the table, which is a problem. The fields need to be limited by selecting only the required fields, the request for which would look like:

```
http://localhost:22411/Data/Comp?%24inlinecount=allpages&%24top=1000&%24filter=DistrictCode+eq+%27460800%27&%24select=DistrictCode,DistrictName,DistrictNumber
```

Again, how to configure the grid for this to happen?

I realize the source is available for Kendo UI, but I'm currently still on a trial version which doesn't include the source.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got a workable solution for this myself. I used an idea from this blog post:

http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/zhongchenzhoustipstricksandportaldevelopment/archive/2012/05/20/how-to-use-kendo-ui-datasource-kendo-ui-grid-with-dynamics-crm-2011-rest-endpoint.aspx

I attach an event handler the ajaxSend event, watch for my OData Service URL, and once such a request is detected, append the `select` column list to the URL. Here's the code:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function (e, jqxhr, settings) {
  if (settings.url.toLowerCase().indexOf("@Url.Content(dynDataSource.Url)".toLowerCase()) >= 0) {
      settings.url += "&%24select=@requestColumnList";
  }
});
```

Hope this helps. Still, if someone has got a better solution, I'd like to hear it.

I've also posted this question to Telerik forums: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/framework/data-source/configure-the-kendo-ui-datasource-so-it-would-issue-requests-only-for-specific-displayed-fields.aspx#2131604

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and implemented an approach that constructs an array of included columns in the transport's read `data` callback:

```
dataSource.transport.read.data = function(options) {

    var data = {};

    data["$select"] = columns.map(function(c) {
        return c.field;
    });

    return data;
}
```

If you are using column menu and have hidden columns, you can also filter based on which columns are visible and force a grid refresh as columns are enabled.

```
columnShow: function (e) {
    e.sender.dataSource.read();
}
```